# 【MySql】ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm in trouble with creating user on MySql.

I can see that there is no 'root' user when I run the command below.

mysql> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;

```
+--------------------+-----------+
| User               | Host      |
+--------------------+-----------+
| admin              | %         |
| rds_superuser_role | %         |
| mysql.infoschema   | localhost |
| mysql.session      | localhost |
| mysql.sys          | localhost |
| rdsadmin           | localhost |
+--------------------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, I can't create user 'root'@'localhost',

mysql> create user 'root'@'localhost' identified by '**********';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'

MySql is created on RDS and these commands are run on EC2.

Please help me!

I thought I could create the user 'root'@'localhost'.

Comment: By default, RDS MySQL uses `admin` as the administrative user. Or you can specify whatever administrative username you like when you created the RDS MySQL instance.

Comment: @Vlam, Does this mean RDS MySQL disallows users to create an **administrative user** once a RDS MySQL instance is initialised ? How does it affect creating a user when no privileges have been granted? I wonder if it could be the username 'root' being reserved by RDS MySQL .

Comment: You could try changing `root` to something else and also try `%` instead of `localhost` and see what you get.

Comment: You can also try some of the commands mentioned in https://serverfault.com/questions/961301/cant-create-a-new-user-with-all-privileges-on-aws-rds-mysql-instance